# Find the ratio between the first $2n$ values to the last $2n$ values

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

> Given series with $4n$ values which are in arithmetic progression.
>
> It is given that the sum of the first $3n$ values equal to the last $n$ values. Find the ratio between the first $2n$ values to the last $2n$ values.

*Attempt:*

$$ S_{3n}=S_{4n}-S_{3n}$$

$$\frac{S_{2n}}{S_{4n}-S_{2n}}=?$$

$$\underbrace{\frac{3n(a_1+a_{3n})}{2}}_{S_{3n}}=\underbrace{\frac{4n(a_1+a_{4n})}{2}}_{S_{4n}}-\underbrace{\frac{3n(a_1+a_{3n})}{2}}_{S_{3n}}$$

$$3n(a_1+a_{{3n}})=2n(a_1+a_{4n})=$$

$$...\implies a_1=2a_{4n}-3a_{3n}$$

I am stuck and have no idea how to proceed

Comment: Is it an arithmetic progression?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm translating from other language

Comment: See alternative method in solution posted. No need for messy algebraic manipulations, since it is not required to determine $a, n$ or $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, $$S_{3n} = S_{4n}-S_{3n} \Rightarrow 2S_{3n} = S_{4n}$$ $$\Rightarrow 2\frac{3n}{2}[a + (3n-1)d] = \frac{4n}{2}[a + (4n-1)d]$$ $$\Rightarrow a+(n-1)d =0...(1)$$ Now, we require, $$\frac{S_{2n}}{S_{4n}-S_{2n}} = \frac{n[a +(2n-1)d]}{2n[a +(4n-1)d] -n[a + (2n-1)d]} = \frac{[a + (n-1)d] + nd}{2[a + (n-1)d + 3nd] -[a + (n-1)d + nd]} = \frac{nd}{2(3nd)-nd} = \frac{1}{5}$$ Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

We have that:
$$a_{3n}=a_1+(3n-1)d$$
$$a_{4n}=a_1+(4n-1)d$$
Thus, plugging into your last equation, we get:
$$a_1=2(a_1+(4n-1)d)-3(a_1+(3n-1)d)$$
Solve for $a_1$:
$$a_1=d\frac{1-n}{2}$$
Now, we have:
$$a_{2n}=a_1+(2n-1)d=d\frac{1-n}{2}+(2n-1)d=d\frac{3n-1}{2}$$
$$a_{4n}=a_1+(4n-1)d=d\frac{1-n}{2}+(4n-1)d=d\frac{7n-1}{2}$$
Thus, we have:
$$S_{2n}=\frac{2n(a_1+a_{2n})}{2}=n(d\frac{1-n}{2}+d\frac{3n-1}{2})=n^2d$$
$$S_{4n}=\frac{4n(a_1+a_{2n})}{2}=2n(d\frac{1-n}{2}+d\frac{7n-1}{2})=6n^2d$$
Finally:
$$\frac{S_{2n}}{S_{4n}-S_{2n}}=\frac{n^2d}{6n^2d-n^2d}=\frac{n^2d}{5n^2d}=\frac{1}{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for an AP of $4n$ numbers, sums of groups of consecutive $n$ numbers also form an AP.

For the given AP, add numbers in groups of $n$ to form a new AP comprising $4$ numbers:

$$\begin{align}
&A, &A+D, &&A+2D, &&A+3D\end{align}$$

Given that $S_3=T_4$, we have
$$3A+3D=A+3D\qquad\Rightarrow A=0$$
Hence the new AP is 
$$\begin{align}
&0, &D, &&2D, &&3D\end{align}$$

From this we can easily deduce that

$$\frac {S_2}{S_4-S_2}=\frac {T_1+T_2}{T_3+T_4}=\color{red}{\frac 15}$$

This avoids messy algrebraic manipulations and is useful since we do not need to find the $a$ or $d$ of the original AP.